# Handling multiple notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am using an app that issues many local notifications at a time. My issue is if there is more than one outstanding notification, clicking on a notification will cause the other(s) notification to be ignored. So is there any way to effectively track multiple notifications? Or even more specifically, find out which notifications were not received by the app delegate?

Comment: the best way is to maintain a database for the notifications as i did in one of my application which is handling multiple notifications.

Comment: Thank you. I just wish that wasn't so much work. Really appreciated the help.